# Egrep first few characters in each line?

Tags: grep

Lets say I have a text file

**txt.txt**

```
hello supdijfdsfsddsgs
hghgh hsdjghjfhgjfhgjfhg
hghgh yyyyyereuryueyruey
```

I want to print the lines such that only first `5` characters are the sequence `hghgh`?

So, it should print

```
    hghgh hsdjghjfhgjfhgjfhg
    hghgh yyyyyereuryueyruey
```

How should the egrep be?

```
egrep -5 "hghgh" txt.txt
```

?

Answer (score 4):

This would do it:

```
grep '^hghgh' txt.txt
```

`egrep` is just `grep -E` (just like `fgrep` is `grep -F`), but the `-E` is not needed here since we don't need to use extended regular expressions.

The (basic) regular expression `^hghgh` matches the literal string `hghgh` at the start of the line.  It's the `^` that anchors the pattern to the start of the line.

If you want to match the *exact* string `hghgh` at the start of the line and not e.g. `hghghaaaaaa` (where `hghgh` is a substring), then use `\>` or `\b` or `[[:>:]]` at the end of the expression to match the end of that word:

```
grep '^hghgh\>' txt.txt
```

Or, use `awk` and do a string comparison with the first field:

```
awk '$1 == "hghgh"' txt.txt
```

Comment: Note that the `awk` one would match on `␠␠␠␠␠␠␠hghgh` and wouldn't match on `hghgh-whatever` (contrary to the `\>` approaches). See also `grep -E '^.{0,3}hghgh'` to look for `hghgh` within the first 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat.

With `grep` (`grep -E` and `egrep` will also work, but this is barebones `grep` at work here):

```
grep '^hghgh' /path/to/input
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^hghgh/p' /path/to/input
sed '/^hghgh/!d' /path/to/input
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^hghgh/' /path/to/input
```

Which is short for:

```
awk '/^hghgh/ { print $0 }' /path/to/input
```

Or

```
awk 'index($0, "hghgh") == 1' /path/to/input
```

Or

```
awk 'substr($0, 1, 5) == "hghgh"' /path/to/input
```